# How to Protect Fusion table layer without paying $10000 to google?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm developing few unique maps and would like to publish them on my website but it means that I should make these maps "public" and anyone can download it. Project is not for profit that's why there is no way I will pay for google maps api business account, but it would be nice to protect my maps somehow. Could you tell me is there any way to do that without paying $10000 to google?

Thank you for your help!

P.S It is a public website

P.S P.S I don't think that google would give a grant for this...

Comment: Use your own database instead of asking Google to do all the work for you.

Comment: You could consider to use [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Google Maps API for free on a non-public website violates the terms of service, so there is no way to do exactly what you are asking.

You could apply for a [Google Outreach Grant](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/grants/software/index.html) for non-profits to use Google Maps API for  Business

If that is not an option, you could technically change the shared status of your table from "Public" to "Anyone with the link." This is obviously not private, but someone would have to dig into your javascript code in order to find the source table.  And if your map is not public, it is not likely that someone would discover your data.  But while this might be technically possible, it still violates the terms of service.